# Reagrupar itens repetidos de um array

Tags: php

Boa tarde.

Atualmente eu possuo um formulário dinâmico onde a pessoa pode adicionar os seguintes valores:

Categoria | Titulo | Descrição

O que eu faço até o momento: Pego cada linha ((int) Categoria/ (string) Titulo / (String) Descricao) e insiro no meu banco de dados pegando o ID que o mesmo retorna. A coluna "Categoria" contém valores fixos num droplist, e pode ocorrer de ter linhas com a mesma categoria, eu preciso AGRUPAR estes itens repetidos (ou não) em outro array

Um exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [categoria] => 1 
            [titulo] => teste 1
            [descricao] => teste 1
            [id_no_banco] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [categoria] => 2
            [titulo] => teste 2
            [descricao] => teste 2
            [id_no_banco] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [categoria] => 1
            [titulo] => teste 3
            [descricao] => teste 3
            [id_no_banco] => 3
        )

)
```

O que eu preciso é: independente de repetir ou não, criar um segundo array que fique parecido com isso:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_categoria] => 1
            [ids_do_banco] => 1;3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_categoria] => 2
            [ids_do_banco] => 2
        )
)
```

Repare que as categorias repetidas do índice 0 e 2 estão "agrupadas" na nova array, e é isso que não estou conseguindo achar uma solução, alguém pode me dar uma luz? obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer um simples `foreach`, considerando:

```
$array = [
    [
        'categoria' => 1,
        'titulo' => 'teste 1',
        'descricao' => 'teste 1',
        'id_no_banco' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'categoria' => 2,
        'titulo' => 'teste 2',
        'descricao' => 'teste 2',
        'id_no_banco' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'categoria' => 1,
        'titulo' => 'teste 3',
        'descricao' => 'teste 3',
        'id_no_banco' => 3,
    ]
];
```

Faça:

```
foreach($array as $item){

    if(isset($categoria[$item['categoria']])){
        $categoria[$item['categoria']] .= ';' . $item['id_no_banco'];
    }else{
        $categoria[$item['categoria']] = (string)$item['id_no_banco'];
    }

}
```

Isso iria retornar:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "1;3"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Que já pode ser suficiente, onde os indexes/chaves da array (`[1]` e `[2]`) representam a `categoria` e o seu valor o `id_no_banco`.

---

Se realmente quiser algo como mencionou poderia utilizar:

```
foreach($array as $item){

    if(isset($categoria[$item['categoria']])){
        $categoria[$item['categoria']]['id_no_banco'] .= ';' . $item['id_no_banco'];
    }else{
        $categoria[$item['categoria']]['categoria'] =  $item['categoria'];
        $categoria[$item['categoria']]['id_no_banco'] = (string)$item['id_no_banco'];
    }

}
```

Neste caso ainda sim seria possível obter a informação pelo index e também haveria a informação de `categoria` e `id_no_banco`, resultando em:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["categoria"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_no_banco"]=>
    string(3) "1;3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["categoria"]=>
    int(2)
    ["id_no_banco"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Você pode utilizar o `array_values($categoria)` ou até mesmo `sort($categoria)` para reordenar a array, assim partindo o `0` e não relacionado com a categoria em si.

---

Uma outra opção seria utilizar `array_search` e o `array_column`, porém fazendo isso irá fazer, internamente, mais um loop.

```
foreach($array as $item){

    $coluna = array_column($categoria, 'categoria');
    $index = array_search($item['categoria'], $coluna, true);

    if($index !== false){
        $categoria[$index]['id_no_banco'] .= ';' . $item['id_no_banco'];
    }else{
        $categoria[] = [
                        'categoria' =>  $item['categoria'],
                        'id_no_banco' => (string)$item['id_no_banco'],
                       ];
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["categoria"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id_no_banco"]=>
    string(3) "1;3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["categoria"]=>
    int(2)
    ["id_no_banco"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, quebrei tanto a cabeça por algo relativamente simples, muito obrigado!